# What runway has the steepest climb requirement on take-off?

Tags: takeoff

What runway has the steepest climb-out requirement upon take off?

This would probably be due to the need to avoid some natural obstacle, such as a mountain.

Answer (score 4):

The first one that came to mind is London City Airport (EGLC) which is world famous for its steep approaches, and for which I found these requirements on its [departure charts](https://www.aurora.nats.co.uk/htmlAIP/Publications/2020-04-23-AIRAC/graphics/142741.pdf):

> OBSTACLE CLEARANCE -
>   RWY 09: Maintain minimum 6.76% climb gradient to 275 (258).
>   RWY 27: Maintain minimum 7.20% climb gradient to 1102 (1085).

(Where the first number is altitude in feet and the second number is AAL, above aerodrome level)

Comment: Is John Wayne/Orange County/Santa Anna (SNA) at all competitive here? (noise abatement)